# Show all sequence of $l^1$ with $|x_n|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

Could you help me to check my proof:

let $\{x^k\}$ be a sequence in such set, we use Cantor's diagonal argument to show the existence of convergent subsequence.

There exists a subsequence $\{x^{\sigma_1(k)}\}$ ($\sigma_1:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, strickly increasing) such that the first coordinate $\{x^{\sigma_1(k)}_1\}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$. We can take a further subsequence $\{x^{\sigma_2\circ \sigma_1(k)}\}$ converges at the second coordinate $\{x^{\sigma_2\circ \sigma_1(k)}_2\}$, etc. Now we take the diagional sequence 
$$\{x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)}\}_{k=1}^\infty,$$
 this sequence converges at each coordinate, let us call the sequence of coordinates limit $y$. We have $|y_n|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$, thus $y\in l^1$.

To show $x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)} \rightarrow y$ in $l^1$, we have that 
$$\| x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)} - y\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg|x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)}_n - y_n\bigg|,$$
break the sum at some $N$ such that $\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{1}{n^2}\leq\epsilon$
$$\| x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)} - y\| = \sum_{n<N} \bigg|x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)}_n - y_n\bigg| + \sum_{n\geq N}^\infty \bigg|x^{\sigma_k \circ\cdots \cdot\sigma_1(k)}_n - y_n\bigg|.$$
The second part is less than $\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{2}{n^2} \leq 2\epsilon$, the first part goes to zero as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you could just use the fact that this is the image of the product space $[-1,1]^\mathbb N$ (which is compact by Tychonoff) under a continuous map
$$ T: (x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots) \to ( x_1, x_2/2^2, x_3/3^2, \ldots)$$

Comment: What norm (topology) would I use on the domain, and I guess we should use the $l^2$ norm on the codomain. Thanks.

Comment: $T$ takes $[-1,1]^\mathbb N$ with the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) (as implied by "product space") to $l^1$ with the $l^1$ norm (why on earth would you want the $l^2$ norm there?)

Comment: Ah, sorry I meant $l^1$

Comment: Okay, I will try to show that $T$ is continuous. Since the product topology is the pointwise convergence topology, suppose $x^n$ converges to $x$ pointwise, then we want $\|Tx^n - Tx\|$ to be small. Take $N$ large such that $$\|Tx^n - Tx\| = \sum_{j\leq N} |Tx^n_j - Tx_j| + \sum_{j> N} |Tx^n_j - Tx_j |$$ where the second sum (bounded by  $\sum_{j> N} \frac{2}{j^2}$)  is small, and then take $n\rightarrow \infty$ the first sum will go to zero,

Comment: In other words, given $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \in [-1,1]^{\mathbb N}$, take $N$ so $\sum_{j > N} 1/j^2 < \epsilon/2$.  If $y \in [-1,1]^{\mathbb N}$ with $|y_j - x_j| < \epsilon/(2N)$ for $j \le N$, then $\|T(x) - T(y)\| < \epsilon$.  Thus we have found a neighbourhood of $x$ in the product topology that is mapped into the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $T(x)$.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that this works if instead of $|x_n|\leq 1/n^2$ we say $|x_n|<k_n, $ provided that  $ \sum_nk_n <\infty.$